# how do I set a variable in postgres sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a psql script that has lots of inserts, and I want one of the numbers I insert into a table to be relative to a specific number that I draw from a table.

I tried to do it as following:

```
select @max_a = max(a) + 1 from tableA;
insert into ... values (@max_a + 5)
```

but I get an error on the first select statement (ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@").

I tried to replace it with

```
  set @max_a = (select max(a) + 1 from tableA);
```

but that didn't work either (I get ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@").

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your error

Comment: Why cant you do it like this  `insert into yourtable(column) select max(a) + 1 from tableA`

Comment: @GavinCattell done. cableload, don't want to do multiple selects like this, I want to set that value as a variable to use multiple times.

Comment: I've not seen that use of variables in SQL before. In the above case I'd create dynamic SQL, or use a temporary table to store the value during execution.

Comment: If you want to reuse the variable, you probably want to consider using plpgsql The type of assignment you are looking is not available in postgresql (that is within sql)